# mysqli_real_escape_string oop Нужна помощь в синтаксисе

Tags: php, mysqli

Ребята, здравствуйте.
Есть корявый процедурный код который писал индус левой ногой. (шутка только про ногу, индус писал реально)
Я учусь php и поставил себе задачу переписать этот код в ООП. Но возник вопрос с real_escape_string методом. Верный ли синтаксис в этой строке?

`$email = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["newAccUserEmail"]);`

$db экземпляр класса базы данных с подключением. ($db = new Database($dbhost, бла бла бла);)
$_POST["newAccUserEmail"] - приходит из Unity. Доходит точно. Не пустой.

На всякий случай весь код:

```
if(isset($_POST["newAccUserEmail"])){ // Если существует запрос в переменной пост которая приходит из юнити    

    $email = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["newAccUserEmail"]);
    $password = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["newAccPassword"]);

    // Проверяем чтобы поля не были пустыми
    if($email != "" && $password != ""){

        $account = $db->query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ?', $email)->fetchArray();

        if ($account['email'] == 0) {

            $db->query('INSERT INTO accounts (email, password) VALUES (?,?)', $email, $password);

            echo "Регистрация: email " . $email . " and password: " . $password; // Текст который выводится в public Text info;

        }else{
            echo "Этот email уже зарегистрирован.";
        }       
    }else{
        echo "Оба поля обязательны. Введите свой email и придумайте пароль.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну допустим верный. Дальше-то что?)

Comment: Но если используются prepared statemet - особо смысла не имеет

Comment: Хм... просто он НЕ работает.
Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Database::real_escape_string() in C:\OpenServer\domains\hstest.loc\index.php:50
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in ****test.loc\index.php on line 50<br />

Comment: так значит вопрос не правильно или нет, а в том что значит проблема в том что подключения нет.  смотреть надо ошибки подключения....... это же mysqli? ..... хотя бы включить  https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php#refsect1-mysqli.real-escape-string-examples   mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

Comment: Да вот самое то интересное, что подключение к БД есть. 
Проверка подключения к БД пишет "успешное подключение".
Грешу на то, что код не в классе и не в функции записан... 
Но я только учусь и многих нюансов могу не понимать.

Comment: "что код не в классе и не в функции записан" --- ???

Comment: у вас точно mysqli  а не mysql?

Comment: Да, точно mysqli так как пыха 7 и процедурный код работал. Перестал работать когда переписал в ООП

Answer (score 0):

Ошибку нашёл. Была она не в коде, а в БД Mysql. Строчка `name` не была установлена в NULL по умолчанию. Не думал что я такой не внимательный